# 2amigos Daterangepicker is not working in Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

I need to filter my records in `GridView` by date range, for example: `01-05-2015` to `09-05-2015`.

I am trying to use `DateRangePicker` from [this extension](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget) for this, but it`s not working:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'created_at')->widget(DateRangePicker::className(), [
    'attributeTo' => 'date_to',
    'model' => $model, // best for correct client validation
    'language' => 'en',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-m-dd'
    ],
]) ?>
```

If I set `start_date` and `end_date`, it should show the record created between these dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got an answer,

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'createdat', $this->createdat, $this->created_at]);
```

Comment: So it's not problem with `DateRangePicker`? You should simply ask instead "How to add condition for filter between two dates to `ActiveQuery`?"